# English sentence structure of a 'if' phrase

Tags: syntactic-analysis

'Because my legs haven't disabled me, if anything they've enabled me.'

It seems to me that there is something omitted. Because as far as I know, it needs a subject and a verb after 'if', but there is no verb after it. Could anyone explain this structure?

Comment: 'Because it's not raining, it's sunny' is false reasoning. // Grammatically, there's not much wrong. Think of it as two sentence fragments. _The critic who criticised my rather long legs was wrong. Because my legs haven't disabled me. If anything, they've enabled me._

Answer (score 1):

> Because my legs haven't disabled me, if anything they've enabled me.

The sentence as it stands it either entirely ungrammatical or else it adopts the colloquialism of starting a new sentence with "because" that had a pretty long statement preceding it.

Example of this construction:

> I don't need to listen to my parents. Because I'm a 15-year-old knowitall.

It's often seen in editorials, but it's not proper.

Also, you have two separate thoughts in play. Since<sup>1</sup> they are closely related, this type of construction usually has a semicolon separating them.

> My legs haven't disabled me; if anything, they've enabled me.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I was tempted to use "because" here, though it's grammatically distinct from the because I mentioned above.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

"Because" is unnecessary and makes this sentence sound awkward. Also, there is a verb in the "if phrase" - "enabled." A comma after "anything" would certainly add clarity. Or, a semicolon after the first "me."